# How textbox works as IP address box

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, ip

My question is that can we create a textbox like IP address box means we can insert only numeric value in textbox like `"122.235.25.36"` and all dots (.) already remains there.

I am making a app. in which I want to assign any IP in particular format as we see in network place for configure a network IP.
If this is possible in c# asp.net with jquery/javascript, tell me.

Comment: Regular expressions will be your friend here.

Comment: "Please provide me proper solution" does not really go down well here :)

What have you tried? Have you heard of regular expressions? Can be useful here when incorporated with keypress/keydown event handler.

Comment: I know regular expression but that's work on string that should be completed. but I want to this at input time

Comment: Question has been reformatted to meet the quality guidelines, nominated for reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) lets you specify a format such as this.

```
$("#ip").mask("999.999.999.999");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex and match on the following expression with the following JavaScript function:

```
function checkValidIPAddress() {
 var regex = "\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"

 var str = $("#inputBox").val();
 var pattern = new RegExp(regex);
 return pattern.test(str);
}
```

Where `#inputBox` is the ID of the control you wish to validate.

**Demonstration of this code working:**

http://jsfiddle.net/MHKkX/

**From the comments:**

function checkValidIPAddress() {
     var regex = "^(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$";

```
 var str = $("#inputBox").val();
 var pattern = new RegExp(regex);
 return pattern.test(str);
```

}

```
$("#inputBox").keyup(function() {
  if (checkValidIPAddress()) {
     $("#error").hide();  
  } else {
    $("#error").show();   
 }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MHKkX/7/

Comment: your jsfiddle not proper working here and its check after complete the string but I want to this at input time.

Comment: @Ghost - I can amend it after for a keyup change etc.  I posted the fiddle to demonstrate the javascript function was working.

Comment: I checked this by string 'dfdskk 12'but this does not give any error message.

Comment: @Ghost - ahh thats because jquery was not loaded on the fiddle:

Comment: @Ghost - on the left hand side ensure jquery 1.9 is selected (2nd combobox) - it is not saving the framework for some reason.

Comment: Ok now this works but I want to this at input time and it works on enter click after complete the string. right.

Comment: @Ghost - updated: http://jsfiddle.net/MHKkX/7/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24513/discussion-between-ghost-answer-and-darren-davies)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Jquery plugin:

http://mlntn.com/2009/12/30/jquery-ip-address-plugin/

and demo is:

http://mlntn.com/demos/jquery-ipaddress/